# How to convert a string with numbers and spaces into an int

Tags: php, string, numbers

I have a small problem. I am tryng to convert a string like "1 234" to a number:1234
I cant't get there. The string is scraped fro a website. It is possible not to be a space there? Because I've tried methods like str_replace and preg_split for space and nothing. Also (int)$abc takes only the first digit(1).
If anyone has an ideea, I'd be greatefull! Thank you!

Comment: Assuming you've got that string in a variable, do a var_dump() on it, as well as view the source of the webpage you're outputting it to. It may look like only a single space, but remmber that there's many space-like characters, and browsers collapse consecutive spaces into a single one for display purposes. It could be `1<tab><cr><lf><space><non-breaking space>234` for all you know, and all those special characters would be hidden from view.

Comment: in the source code I have 1 234. I've tried intval(str_replace(' ','',$str)) and all I get is a 1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how I would handle it...

```
<?php

$string = "Here! is some text, and numbers 12 345, and symbols !£$%^&";

$new_string = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $string);

echo $new_string // Returns 12345

?>
```

Comment: Putting `\s` into the pattern leaves the OP with the exact same problem. Two numbers separated by one or more spaces and/or space-like characters.

Comment: You could also use the alias: `preg_replace("/\D/", "", $string)`

Answer (score 8):

```
intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $input))
```

Comment: This might be the best bet here, as this will remove other space characters as described in @Marc's comment.

Comment: Thank's! It's working. I still can't understand why str_replace doesn't do the job :-?

Comment: @Iosub Because you're not listing *all* whitespace characters, for example not `\t`

Answer (score 4):

Scraping websites always requires specific code, you know how you receive the input - and you write code that is required to make it usable.

That is why first answer is still str_replace.

```
$iInt = (int)str_replace(array(" ", ".", ","), "", $iInt);
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing `)` after `","`.

Comment: @Phoenix, yes @Wesley did, duly fixed now though.

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = "1 234";
$int = intval(str_replace(' ', '', $str)); //1234
```

Comment: nop, it's not working. intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $input)) made the job. Thank's anyway.

Comment: That will fail when `$str = 'abc1234'`

Answer (score 0):

I've just came into the same issue, however the answer that was provided wasn't covering all the different cases I had...

So I made this function (the idea popped in my mind thanks to Dan) :

```
function customCastStringToNumber($stringContainingNumbers, $decimalSeparator = ".", $thousandsSeparator = " "){
    $numericValues = $matches = $result = array();
    $regExp = null;
    $decimalSeparator = preg_quote($decimalSeparator);
    $regExp = "/[^0-9$decimalSeparator]/";
    preg_match_all("/[0-9]([0-9$thousandsSeparator]*)[0-9]($decimalSeparator)?([0-9]*)/", $stringContainingNumbers, $matches);
    if(!empty($matches))
        $matches = $matches[0];
    
    foreach($matches as $match):
        $numericValues[] = (float)str_replace(",", ".", preg_replace($regExp, "", $match));
    endforeach;
    $result = $numericValues;
    if(count($numericValues) === 1)
        $result = $numericValues[0];

    return $result;
}
```

So, basically, this function extracts all the numbers contained inside of a string, no matter how many text there is, identifies the decimal separator and returns every extracted number as a float.

One can specify what decimal separator is used in one's country with the $decimalSeparator parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for removing any other characters like `.,:"'\/`, `!@#$%^&*()`, `a-z`, `A-Z` :

```php
$string = "This string involves numbers like 12 3435 and 12.356 and other symbols like !@# then the output will be just an integer number!";

$output = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string));

var_dump($output);
```