# Php - remove text units from a number

Tags: php, jquery, string, replace

I have the following line in a php file that grabs a value and returns it as a jQuery variable:

```
var HeaderWrapperHeightNEW = <?php if(get_theme_mod('header_image_full_size') != '1'){ echo get_theme_mod('header_height');}?>;
```

My problem is that sometimes the returned result has a letter unit after it, for example 600px or 50% - I just need it to echo the number and not the unit. Is this possible to do? And how would I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307827/how-to-convert-a-string-with-numbers-and-spaces-into-an-int

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239136/fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-php,

Answer (score 3):

You could use the PHP function [floatval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php/):

```
<?php
$str = '-10.5px';
$str = floatval($str);
echo $str; // -10.5
?>
```

You could also use type casting:

```
<?php
$str = '-10.5px';
$str = (float)$str;
echo $str; // -10.5
?>
```

Note:

- It also handles a minus symbol and a float. '`10px`' would still
  return just `10` but is a float.
- If only integers should be returned use `$str = (int)$str;` instead.
- Nothing should precede the value.
  `$str = 'margin: -10.5px';` would return `0` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

This will clean up all non-digits from the string:

```
string_with_units.replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
```

Comment: This happens on the JavaScript side, not in PHP. In PHP, use functions like [floatval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) or [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to parse a float or an integer from a string.